# Comparison of two datasets and assignment of associated values into a new variable (in R)

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, case

I have two datasets. One dataset (here df1) is the information dataset, containing all the known values with their corresponding assignments. These assignments now need to be mapped to the values in df2 (if a value doesn't exist in df1, it will be given a 'no assignment').

There should be a solution using case_when or if_else. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. I would greatly appreciate a solution!

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  value = c("dfg","jel", "eow", "lüw", "ced", "wrt", "gle", "üäp", "flq"),
  assign =c(NA, 0, 1, NA, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0))
```

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  numb = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
  value = c("eow", "lüw", "lwi", "ced", "jel", "dfg", "wrt"))
```

This should be the result:

```
df_result <- data.frame(
  numb = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
  value = c("eow", "lüw", "lwi", "ced", "jel", "dfg", "wrt"),
  assign = c(1, NA, "no assignment", 1, 0, NA, 0))
```

I already tried:
`df2$assign <- ifelse(df2$value %in% df1$value, df1$assign, "no assigment")`

However, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Have a look at the `merge` function (or `left_join` if you are using the `tidyverse`)

Comment: Thank you!! That was it!